# Visual Studio Code language support for java crashed 5 times

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm using `Visual Studio Code` languagage support for `Java` made by `Red Hat` but I'm getting an error:

```
The server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes the server will not be restarted.
```

I have removed the app and reinstall two times.
I have installed lombok annotations nothing.

===MY LOG HEAD UNTILL THE ERROR ====

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.8
java.vendor=Ubuntu
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -data /home/icomg/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/dd03d70bdc61fd3884317d660a873358/redhat.java/jdt_ws

This is a continuation of log file /home/icomg/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/dd03d70bdc61fd3884317d660a873358/redhat.java/jdt_ws/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2020-08-25 08:29:55.231

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core 4 0 2020-08-25 08:29:55.231
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.JavaLanguageServerPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1838)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1743)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceManager.initialize(PreferenceManager.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceManager.<init>(PreferenceManager.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.preferences.StandardPreferenceManager.<init>(StandardPreferenceManager.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.JavaLanguageServerPlugin.start(JavaLanguageServerPlugin.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:835)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core (41).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

My OS is `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`

`Vscode -v 1.48.0`

Language support version `0.65.0`
```

Comment: Do you have any logs from server startup?

Comment: I have added some logs from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to be bug with the current folder .I have resolved the problem by creating a new folder and move my project there .